# Codeigniter: Fat models vs Libraries

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, models

i am new to codeigniter, the question @ headline has been asked before, but i'm not yet convinced.

If i am creating a registration and login system, it would include functions such as

```
(login(),forgot_pass(), remember_me,register(),etc).
```

So where is it best to keep their definitions:a model(fat model)or a super model or in a different library altogether, in the latter technique it would be less of object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

As a library you just need to load the library and you can use it in any controller, model or view.

```
$this->load->library('my_library_name');  
$this->my_library_name->do_something();
```

As a model, you could do the same as the library:

```
$this->load->model('my_model_name');  
$this->my_model_name->do_something();
```

Other methods, like helpers, are not practical. I did it as a library. I just liked it this way.
To answer to your question: do as you see fit or as you like it.

**LE:** Take a look at [TankAuth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) for `CodeIgniter`, maybe it will get you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

As machineaddict said when you need to call your function in your library file you need to load it first.

```
$this->load->library('you_library_name');
$this->you_library_name->function_name();
```

Additionally, if you want to use it as global function just put your function out of the class. Once the library is loaded, you can just use your function() without `$this->you_library_name->function_name();`